# Are questions related to (Mozilla) Pocket software on topic?

Tags: support, on-topic

Giving that even after reading other online resorces such as:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_(service)
- https://getpocket.com/developer/docs/overview

I still would have some concrete/factual questions about this Pocket software, which other persons, such as users, or developers might easily be able to give me answer.

Is superuser.com a valid SE community for that, meaning is this on topic?

**update**

I appreciate very much the informative answer provided by @Mokubai♦ below and if allowed would sketch the context I wanted to ask the question, as to allow a more conclusive feedback regarding if it would be fitting/ok/ontopic to ask it on superuser. My Pocket related answer would have been similar to those:

1. Does Pocket allow to read webpages offline (no internet connection) by means of the Firefox browser **only**, or require other software to do this (such as a desktop program, or a  smartphone App, or another software)?
2. In what form are webpages stored for offline viewing (verbatim or transformed?)

I would imagine the second quetion being excessively technical however. The main inquiry was however the first one, which I would imagine to be perfectly answerable, but I was unable to find a conclusive answer, nor able to test it. The value I would see in an answered question would be that it would allow users to know what functionality they can expect from Firefox/Mozilla's Pocket software. I for instance expected it to be able to allow me to keep offline copies of webpages (for reading in places without internet), but have up to know not been able to achieve this with the Firefox Browser.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what feature of Pocket you are asking about.

If you are asking about features that operate primarily on your desktop or laptop computer such as the addon that works within your browser then it could well be on topic here.

If you are asking about the website or web application then [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place for it.

For integration with or applications on other platforms then it would be better on those platforms Stack site as mobile phones and "random electronics" are off topic here.

- https://android.stackexchange.com/
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/
- https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

If it is about how the backend works and how posts are transferred between platforms then it is probably too broad, too programming focused and cannot be guessed by "normal" users then it may not have a place on the network. You might be better off contacting the developers directly.

Without more concrete information on what questions you are going to ask all I can say is that each question would have to be taken on a case-by-case basis. You should really read the `/help/on-topic` page for each site (i.e. https://superuser.com/help/on-topic, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to find out what is on or off topic for each site.

Comment: I believe Pocket is bundled with Firefox. Where would that version be accepted?

Comment: @Burgi It's not built into my version on desktop or Android as far as I can see but if it was the version built in to Firefox on a desktop then [su], otherwise on the platform on which the copy of Firefox is installed.